# How to configure Graphite & Grafana with spark submit on Airflow cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, graphite, grafana, airflow

I recently configured `Airflow` to perform my tasks. I've got master node and 2 workers that perform my tasks.
I want to monitor my cluster with `Graphite` and `Grafana`.
All I did was installing `Graphite` and `Grafana` on master node and testing it with simple bash command.
Now I want to monitor my `Airflow` cluster while executing task.
I created  `metrics.properties` and placed it in `spark/conf`:

```
# Enable Graphite
*.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
*.sink.graphite.host=192.168.2.241
*.sink.graphite.port=2003
*.sink.graphite.period=10

# Enable jvm source for instance master, worker, driver and executor
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

And I added following flags to my `spark-submit`:

```
--files=/path/to/metrics.properties \
--conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties
```

All I can find after opening `Graphite ui` is `Graphite->carbon->agents->cluster1-a` with some graphs. I'm sure it's monitoring something else and not my `Airflow` cluster.

Maybe I need to install `grafana-spark-dashboards`? But it is all about `YARN` and I'm using `Airflow` management system.
Or add a block to `Carbon`’s `storage-schemas.conf`?
This block will be diplayed in `Graphite` dashboard:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d
```

Can I check somehow which metrics `Spark` send to `Graphite`?

Comment: The data you are seeing in graphite is graphite monitoring itself, and that is also the carbon retention you are seeing. You should not need to install a grafana dashboard to see things in graphite. I suggest walk through graphite's starting docs wherein you submit data manually to get used to it before jumping into all this at once. But my guess is that you need to add a retention for the metrics you are adding. To find out check the graphite (or carbon or whisper or whatever) logs for errors.